# Fixing instability in custom bce+dice loss metric

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I am having a hard time implementing a custom loss function. I believe there is an issue with numerical instability, but I am not familiar enough with this to fix the issue myself. The loss function in question is the combination of Dice loss and binary cross entropy.

Here is my custom function definition:

```
def dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred):
     smooth = 1.
     # Flatten
     y_pred_f = tf.cast(tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1]),'float32')
     y_true_f = tf.cast(tf.reshape(y_true, [-1]),'float32')

     intersection = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(y_true_f,y_pred_f))
     score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f) + tf.reduce_sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
     return score

 def dice_loss(y_true,y_pred):
     loss = 1-dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred)
     return loss

 def bce_dice_loss(y_true,y_pred):
     loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(tf.cast(tf.reshape(y_true, [-1]),'float32'), tf.cast(tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1]),'float32')) + dice_loss(y_true, y_pred)
     return loss
```

'''

I only have an issue with the combination bce_dice_loss:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't numerical instability but y_pred using unnormalized logits. Converting y_pred to a normalized probability (using a sigmoid function here) and adding from_logits=True to the bce+dice loss solved the problem. Generally, if the dice loss returns a negative value, check to see if you are inputting logits or normalized probabilities.